# django admin how to add context when using custom action button?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a custom action button "Add post" for each record in my admin panel. I want to save in context `obj.id` to use it for a default value in `admin:channels_post_add` form

```
class ChannelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title','username', 'invite_link', 'account_actions']

    def account_actions(self, obj):

        !!!! I WANT TO ADD CONTEXT HERE!!!!

        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">Add post</a>', reverse('admin:channels_post_add'))

    account_actions.short_description = 'Actions'
    account_actions.allow_tags = True

    class Meta:
        model = Channel

admin.site.register(Channel, ChannelAdmin)





class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['text', 'media', 'send_type', 'created']

    class Meta:
        model = Post


    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PostAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        try:

            post_id = !!! AND USE IT HERE!!!!

            form.base_fields['channels'].initial = post_id
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add GET parameters to the url.

```
url = "%s?pid=%s" % (reverse(admin:channels_post_add), obj.id)
```

And then `request.GET.get("pid")` in `get_form()`:

```
class ChannelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def account_actions(self, obj):
        url = "%s?pid=%s" % (reverse(admin:channels_post_add), obj.id)
        return format_html('<a class="button" href="{}">Add post</a>', url)



class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(PostAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        try:
            form.base_fields['channels'].initial = request.GET.get("pid")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return form
```

I think you have to use [**`ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data(request)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data)) to set initial value.

> A hook for the initial data on admin change forms. By default, fields
> are given initial values from **GET** parameters. For instance,
> **?name=initial_value** will set the **name** field’s initial value to be
> **initial_value**.
>
> This method should return a dictionary in the form **{'fieldname':
> 'fieldval'}**:

```
url = "%s?channels=%s" % (reverse(admin:channels_post_add), obj.id)
```

or

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    return {'channels': request.GET.get("pid")}
```

Comment: getting `Channel with ID “%s” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?` when clicking on that url

Comment: @yaschk1999, Have you checked , is it present in db?

Comment: yes that channel exists,  this is a button after pressing which a form for creating a post (another model not channel model) opens and I want the post to be immediately assigned a default channel

Comment: @yaschk1999, can you share full traceback error?

Comment: @yaschk1999, have you tried to use `url = "%s?channels=%s" % (reverse(admin:channels_post_add), obj.id)`. Django must be set initial value from GET params.